# Clear certain columns when importing new csv file, leaving formulas in other columns in place

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a script to automatically import a csv file into a Google sheet. However, I need to process that data with formulas after the import.

I am currently using sheet.clearContents() to clear the entire sheet before importing the new CSV file, but this of course removes my formulas that I want to keep.

How can i specify only to clear columns A:D, while keeping the formulas in column E in tact?

```
sheet.clearContents().clearFormats();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sheet.getRange(1,1,1000,25).clear();
```

Is the answer